# C++ code Runtime error on 2D array declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime-error

I dont understand why is this code giving runtime error on input of any test case (size of string is n, and then string is input). Not even the word "CHECK" (in the solve() function) gets printed.. Please help!

The problem link is : [problem](https://codeforces.com/contest/1385/problem/D)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;


int a[1000][26];
int mov(int l, int u, int x)
{
    if(l==u)
    {
        if(a[l][x]-a[l-1][x]==1)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    int m=(l+u)/2;
    return max(mov(l,m,x+1)+a[u][x]-a[m][x],mov(m,u,x+1)+a[m][x]-a[l-1][x]);
}
void solve()
{
    int i,k,j,n;
    string str;
    cin >> n >> str;
    cout << "CHECK";// This is not getting printed
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
        a[0][i]=0;
    for(i=1;i<n+1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<26;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=a[i-1][j];
            if(str[i-1]==j+'a')
                a[i][j]++;
        }
    }
    k=mov(1,n,0);
    cout << n-k << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    int t=1;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
        solve();
}
```

Comment: Why bother with a while loop for a single function call in your `main()`? Just call `solve()`.

Comment: A problem description of the task you are attempting to accomplish and not just what you perceive to be the problem would also be nice. [ask]

Comment: What happens when `l` will never be equal to `u`? It'll run recursively indefinitely.

Comment: The question link is: [link](https://codeforces.com/contest/1385/problem/D)

Comment: Edit the question, and put the problem text into it. Otherwise this will just get closed.

Comment: @D-RAJ That case shall arise only after the word "CHECK" gets printed, but here it is not so!
Moreover, if you closely go through the code you will find that eventually l shall be equal to u after certain recursive calls!

Comment: @sweenish I am really sorry but I fear I dont know how to edit my question (coz I am new to this site), Could you help me please?

Comment: @sweenish Thanks for your suggestion, I hope I have done the necessary changes!

Comment: [Edit] to quote the full error; I'd hope it gives some more text than that.

Answer (score 0):

Your very first input shows how many input "pairs" will be given. In your case, you have skipped this part and gone into gathering the input "pairs". This is why "CHECK" wont get printed. To resolve this, have a `cin` to capture the number of input pairs, then iterate through the inputs to get the pair.

```cpp
void solve()
{
    int i, k, j, n;
    string str;
    memset(a[0], 0, sizeof(int) * 26); // Use this instead.

    cin >> n;
    cout << "CHECK";     
    for (i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)
    {
        cin >> j >> str;

        for (j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = a[i - 1][j];
            if (str[i - 1] == j + 'a')
                a[i][j]++;
        }
    }
    k = mov(1, n, 0);
    cout << k << "\n";
}
```

Also, try not to use `using namespace std;`.

Comment: I feel like if you are going to go the route of offering extra suggestions, you can't stop at `using namespace std;`. The single variable names, the main function loop, and global array.

Comment: I have updated my code and re-inserted that number of test cases part (I had removed it intentionally so that it doesnt bother people)... The problem still persists